# Can ls show read-only files in a specific color?

Tags: ls, colors, readonly

I like using `ls --color=auto` and I know how to use `dircolors` to change the colors of `ls`'s output. I want `ls` to display read-only files in a color different than "normal" files but don't see an easy way to do that. Have I overlooked something or is this not possible with the standard `ls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with “standard” `ls` (or rather, versions of `ls` supporting colours, and using `dircolors`, so GNU `ls`). `ls`/`dircolors` supports a number of non-extension attributes which can determine colours, but those don’t include “read-only”. You can see the list of attributes [in the `dircolors` source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/dircolors.c?id=041dfff5db1f09c92435e46b65931b04364c37f6#n56), and their description in [the built-in example `dircolors` database](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/dircolors.hin); to see the attributes supported in your own version of `dircolors` and `ls`, run

```
dircolors --print-database
```